# Write a query that select all events ordered by a particular customer in SQL

Tags: sql, database, database-schema

In SQL how we will write a query that selects all events ordered by a particular customer. Kindly help me there.

Thanks

Comment: You must add more details, this can't even be considered a question. We need some background in order to help you.

Comment: This is fairly basic syntax -- please post what you've tried and then we'd be happy to help...

Comment: do you mean events for a customer, or that you want all events but with one particular customer at the top, and the rest ordered by customer?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The table's name is events?...

Select * from events order by custumers asc

if not

select events from Table order by custumers asc

Comment: Your desperation for some points has led you astray. You might want to delete or radically improve this answer before the boys who like to downvote spot it...

Comment: I think my answer is just fine according to the amount of details the post owner gave us

Comment: A poor question doesn't mean you should give a poor answer.

Comment: @Liev04 I didn't vote you down, but a lot of people will. Unlikely guy has a column custumers in his table, more likely Customer_ID, which it isn't likely he would want to order by, and therefore would require a join.